# RStudio: objects masked in an old and removed data frame

Tags: r

I'm an R studio newbie, and I have the following problem:

I have objects masked within a data frame that I previously loaded in the environment and was later removed from it. I am now using a new data frame (very similar to the first one), but the objects are still attached to the old data frame.  How can I unmask that data?

Here's my code lines:

```
str(BmaaMcData)     #**(first data frame)**
rm(BmaaMcData)    

print(BmaaVsMc)     #**(second data frame)**
attach(BmaaVsMc)    

The following objects are masked from BmaaVsMc (pos = 6): BMAA, Sampling Day
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (1) `attach` should really not be used, any lesson that suggests it drastically needs to be updated. (2) Those are warnings indicating that you have some variable named `BMAA` in the global environment as well as a column named `BMAA` in the variable `BmaaVsMc`. Think about it: after `attach` if you type `BMAA`, which of the two do you expect it to use?

Comment: If you `detach(BmaaVsMc)` and then type in `BMAA`, what do you see? Have you `attach`ed any other frame previously and not detached them? Does `ls()` show that you have objects named `BMAA`? If not, does `search()` show anything other than `.GlobalEnv`, `"package:*"`, and `"AutoLoads"`?